# How to open laravel .env file with Vim CtrlP plugin?

Tags: laravel, vim, ctrlp

I am using `vim` with [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin for browsing `laravel` application. The problem is that `CtrlP` working fine for browsing other `.(dot)` such as `.env.example` or `.gitignore` files except for `.env` file of laravel.

Here `CtrlP` working for `.env.example` file
[image]

and here it's working for `.gitignore` file
[image]

This is my `CtrlP` specific configuration from `.vimrc`

```
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['buffertag']

nmap <c-R> :CtrlPBufTag<cr>

set wildignore+=*/vendor/**,*/node_modules/**
set wildignore+=*/public/forum/**
let g:ctrlp_user_command = ['.git/', 'git --git-dir=%s/.git ls-files -oc --exclude-standard']
let g:ctrlp_match_window='order:ttb,min:1,max:15,result:15'
```

Comment: Because you have `.env` in your gitignore? Your user command only list files tracked by git

Comment: Cool that's worked Thanks :)